# How to simulate an equation with variables that change?

Tags: r

The problem is to simulate an equation with variables that change. All the variables are fixed, expect for lower case s and treat_date. Here is the error message:

```
Error in checkFunc(Func2, times, y, rho) : The number of derivatives
returned by func() (202) must equal the length of the initial
conditions vector (2)
```

I have tried moving things around but I honestly have no idea what I am doing

```
seasonal_SI <- function (t, y, parameters) {
  S <- y[1]
  I <- y[2]
  with(as.list(parameters), {     
    julian_date <- t %% 365 
    v <- ifelse(julian_date >= treat_date & 
                  julian_date < (treat_date + 10) &
                  treatment, 0.9, v)  
    beta <- beta0 + s*beta0*sin(2*pi*(julian_date)/365)  
    dSdt <- b*(1-c*(S+I))*(S+rho*I)-d*S-beta*S*I   
    dIdt <- beta*S*I-(d+v)*I   
    res <- c(dSdt, dIdt)    
    list(res)    
  })
}

initials <- c(S=99, I=1)
params <- c(b=.5, c=.01, beta0=5e-3, v=.05, rho=.3, treatment=TRUE,
            s=as.numeric(seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)),
            treat_date=as.numeric(seq(from=0, to=355, length.out=101)))
t <- 0:1

library("deSolve")    
lsoda(y=initials, times=t, parms=params, func=seasonal_SI)
```

I would like for it to run and return a graph.

Comment: Running yout code I got.  Error in ifelse(julian_date >= treat_date & julian_date < (treat_date +  : 
  object 'treat_date' not found

Comment: You should put your parameters into a list rather than into a vector. Try `params <- list(b=.5, c=.01, <...>)`. There are further issues, though, but this could be a start.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the former comment, that you may consider to use a parameter list. However, you may also consider to use a forcing function or the event mechanism.

You find help pages in deSolve:

?forcings
?events

and a short tutorial here: https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html